# Webhook for Google Tasks

Tags: google-tasks

I have integrated Google Tasks APIs into my web application. The requirement is to sync the task between web application and Google.

So far, the Task in my web application is created and synced with the Google Tasks using the Google Tasks API. I want to add logic for syncing the tasks from Google Task to my web application. I have to call the Google Tasks APIs for each task periodically (let say, every 5 minutes) to check the task details and compare across the tasks in the web application and sync it. Calling Google Tasks API periodically consumes too many API calls and the per day quota is 50,000 calls as per google document. This exceeds or will exceed easily.

Quota Limit mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/tasks/pricing)

Requesting to increase quota is an option. But that can be done only if we know the exact or approx API call we require for the day. As it is difficult to estimate the count, I do not prefer to request for more quota.

I want an alternate solution like using a webhook that notifies me if any modification is made on Google Tasks. With that help I can retrieve only modified Google Task and sync back to my web application. This will subsequently consume fewer API calls.

I did some research for the webhook and I found [this](https://zapier.com/apps/google-tasks/integrations/webhook). But I am looking for the webhook provided by Google itself, similar to what they provide for google sheet.

Please help if anyone have integrated webhook for Google Tasks.

Comment: There's no documentation regarding the integration of Webhook using Google Task API. How about creating a task bot? You can check the documentation from Google and use this as a reference with the use of [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook). Here's another [link](https://developer.kore.ai/docs/bots/advanced-topics/bot-store/addingbots/adding-a-google-tasks-bot/) that will help you.